# How to use string from form1 in form2 (how to make them readable in every form?)

Tags: c#

my code from form1 looks like:

```
 public partial class ZarzadzanieZwierzakami : Form
{



    public ZarzadzanieZwierzakami()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

         string z1_wybraneImie = DaneZwierzaka1.z1_wybraneImie;


    }     

    public void btnStworz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var PodanieDanych = new DaneZwierzaka1();
        var ZarzadzanieZwierzakami = new ZarzadzanieZwierzakami();
        this.Hide();
        PodanieDanych.Show();

    }
}

public DaneZwierzaka1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

and in form2 i have:

```
    string z1_wybraneImie;
    string z1_wybranaPlec;
    string z1_wybranaRasa;
    bool imiePoprawne = false;
    bool plecPoprawna = false;
    bool rasaPoprawna = false;


    public void btnGotowe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sprawdzIstworzIMIE(z1_wybraneImie);
        SprawdzIstworzPLEC();
        SprawdzIstworzRASA();


        if (imiePoprawne && rasaPoprawna && plecPoprawna)
        {
            if (chbxImieWielkimi.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Twój zwierzak został pomyślnie utworzony! Imię to: '" + z1_wybraneImie.ToUpper() + "'. Wybrana płeć to: " + z1_wybranaPlec + ", a wybrana rasa to: " + z1_wybranaRasa);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Twój zwierzak został pomyślnie utworzony! Imię to: '" + z1_wybraneImie + "'. Wybrana płeć to: " + z1_wybranaPlec + ", a wybrana rasa to: " + z1_wybranaRasa);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Podane wartości są niepoprawne. Stwórz zwierzaka od nowa");
        }

        txtImie.Text = "";
        cbxPlec.Text = "";
        cbxRasa.Text = "";
    }


    public string sprawdzIstworzIMIE (string z1_wybraneImie)
    {
        if (txtImie.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie wybrałeś imienia. Zrób to, wpisując je w odpowiednim oknie.");
            return null;
        }
        else if (txtImie.Text.Length < 4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Podaj proszę dłuższe imię (min. 4 znaki)");
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            z1_wybraneImie = txtImie.Text;
            imiePoprawne = true;
            return z1_wybraneImie;
        }
    }

    public void SprawdzIstworzPLEC()
    {
        if ((cbxPlec.SelectedIndex == -1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie wybrałeś płci lub wpisałeś błędną wartość. Popraw to, rozwijając odpowiednią listę.");
        }
        else
        {
            z1_wybranaPlec = (cbxPlec.SelectedItem).ToString();
            plecPoprawna = true;
        }
    }

    public void SprawdzIstworzRASA()
    {
        if ((cbxRasa.SelectedIndex == -1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie wybrałeś rasy lub wpisałeś błędną wartość. Popraw to, rozwijając odpowiednią listę.");
        }
        else
        {
            z1_wybranaRasa = (cbxRasa.SelectedItem).ToString();
            rasaPoprawna = true;
        }
    }
```

how can i use strings made in form2 (z1_wybraneImie, z1_wybranaPlec...) in form1? i need to have access to them in every form. i must add that something like `Form1.LabelExample` doesn't work. also .this won't work, i tried it out.

Please helf, if you can :)
I can't add more details :( so i dont know what more to write huh

Answer (score 1):

The properties need to be `public`, and you need to access them through the instance of the form.

e.g.

```
public string z1_wybraneImie;
```

I assume this is your form:

`var PodanieDanych = new DaneZwierzaka1();`

You need to keep hold of that, because you can then do `PodanieDanych.someProperty` to access properties on it.

You might need to pass a reference to your original form into the new form, like this:

```
var PodanieDanych = new DaneZwierzaka1();
PodanieDanych.ParentForm = this; // (Create a public ParentForm of the type of your parent form)
```

Then you can use ParentForm to access the parent and its properties.

Comment: If you created a property on `DaneZwierzaka1` like `public ZarzadzanieZwierzakami ParentForm { get; set; }` then it should work.